# Why doesn't this code work? Trying to find 4 equal values in a row in double array using kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am using a double array to make a grid for a connect four game. using `var gameBoard= Array(8){ Array(8){"."} }` The function I am using to find a horizontal set of 4 is

```kotlin
fun winH(): String {

    for (row in 0 until 7) {
        for (col in 0 until 7) {
            if (
                gameBoard[row][col] == "x"  &&
                gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col + 1] &&
                gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col + 2] &&
                gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col + 3]) {

                return gameBoard[row][col]
            }

        }

    }
    return println(" You have won!").toString()
}
```

When it runs on the first turn it states I have won and only on the first turn.

How do I get it to work when there is 4 in a row of the same value?

I am using the letter "x" and "o" for user input

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First of all until will go fron 0 to 6, you should use `0..7` operator to loop from 0 to 7 or use `0 until 8`. Secondly gameBoard never have "x" so never if condition is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code.

- It only checks for "x". Presumably there is also an "o" or something to represent the other player.
- It either returns the "x" in a winning position or it prints "You have won!" when you have *not* won and then returns the value of `println().toString()`, which evaluates to "kotlin.Unit". Look again at your logic. You iterate the arrays until your if-statement finds a winning row of four. Only if it fails to find any winning rows will it reach the line where it says you won, so it's working in reverse.
- If your 2D array is 8 rows tall, you need to be checking 8 rows, but `0 until 7` is only the numbers from 0 to 6, so you're only checking 7 rows. You should use `0..7`.
- Your 2D array is 8 columns wide, so if you find an "x" in the 6th column or higher, you will start trying to retrieve array values that are out of bounds. So you should only check columns `0..4`.

Since this function is checking for a win, it should return a Boolean. And it should have an input parameter for the symbol you're checking for, so you can use the function for either player, not just `"x"`.

Sample:

```
fun findHorizontalWin(playerSymbol: String): Boolean {
    for (row in 0..7) {
        for (col in 0..4) {
            if (
                playerSymbol == gameBoard[row][col]  &&
                playerSymbol == gameBoard[row][col + 1] &&
                playerSymbol == gameBoard[row][col + 2] &&
                playerSymbol == gameBoard[row][col + 3]) {
                println("Player $playerSymbol has won!")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

With the use of the `all` function, this could be shortened, but I'd only look into this after you're more familiar with the language:

```
fun findHorizontalWin(playerSymbol: String): Boolean {
    for (row in 0..7) {
        for (col in 0..4) {
            if ((0..3).all { playerSymbol == gameBoard[row][col + it] }) {
                println("Player $playerSymbol has won!")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me. I will read on this more.